# Could not Load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AzconfigClient

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-keyvault, azure-app-configuration

I keep getting this exception on the build.

it stops at this line:

```
IConfigurationRoot config = builder.Build();
```

and gives this exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AzconfigClient, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69dad7634abb75e4' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I have tried to add this reference in the packages.config :

```
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AzconfigClient" Version="1.0.0-preview-008870001-1052" targetFramework="net472"/>
```

but it still do not work.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(); //new config builder
            builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString")); //get the connecting string

IConfigurationRoot config = builder.Build(); //call the build method in config builder
```

I am expecting it to build so that I can use the config variable.

Comment: When you are running your application the assembly and its required files should be in your bin/Debug or Release folder . What you have to do is to  open the references section in your project, right click on the reference and it will open the property section and set the  **Copy Local** to true. For additional reference [how-to-resolve-the-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-issues-on-windows-azure-web-sites](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2013/01/09/how-to-resolve-the-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-issues-on-windows-azure-web-sites/)

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration/1.0.0-preview-007830001) which is support .net standard project. For .net it is [preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.azureappconfiguration.azureappconfigurationextensions.addazureappconfiguration?view=azure-dotnet-preview&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet).

Here is a [tutorial](https://zimmergren.net/introduction-azure-app-configuration-store-csharp-dotnetcore/) you could refer to.